# SQL join 2 tables based on third

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 tables:

```
tbl_question (id,question)
tbl_answer (id,answer)
question_has_answer (id,question_id,answer_id)
```

It looks like many-to-many association, but in fact it is only used like 1-to-many (one question has multiple answers, but each answer belongs to only question). So I need to get fields (except id) from first and second table like this:

```
Question1
      answer1
      answer2
      answer3
Question2
      answer5
      answer4
```

and so on.

Comment: I'll edit it since it's confusiong (same tablename and columnname)...which sql you are using btw?

Comment: Ok, then queries posted are all right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would be:

```
SELECT question, answer
    FROM tbl_question q 
    INNER JOIN question_has_answer qha
    ON q.id = qha.question_id
    INNER JOIN tbl_answer a
    ON qha.answer_id = a.id
ORDER BY question,answer
```

I would also recommand not using an ID for table question_has_answer, if you don't plan to use that ID.

And further more: if 1 answer is associated with only 1 question, than you shouldn't use question_has_answer and modify tbl_answer to add a questionID column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
SELECT  b.question, c.answer
FROM    question_has_answer a
        INNER JOIN tbl_question b
            ON a.question_ID = b.ID
        INNER JOIN tbl_answer c
            ON a.answer_ID = c.id
ORDER BY a.question_ID, a.answer_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select question, answer
from tbl_question q
join question_has_answer qa on qa.question_id = q.id
join tbl_answer a on a.id = qa.answer_id
order by 1,2
```

btw, it's irrelevant that "each answer belongs to only one question"; the table structure allows for answers to be used for multiple questions. The fact that they aren't is merely a matter of extant data.

Answer (score 0):

To build on the other answers presented here. The two tables `question_has_answer` and `tbl_answer` should be one table something like `tbl_answers` with(`id`, `question_id`, `answer_id`). There is no need for  two tables, you already can tell if a question is answered or not. If a question has no answers presented in the table `question_has_answer`, then it isn't answered. But for now you can `JOIN` the three tables as pointed out by the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT obj.*,mapping.*,mas.* FROM object_master obj
INNER JOIN mapping_master mapping ON mapping.FMM_Object_ID = obj.FOM_ID
INNER JOIN feedback_master mas ON mapping.FMM_FM_ID = mas.FM_ID
```